# Change Image Size - PHP

Tags: php, image-processing, image-resizing

I have recently created an upload function, but I don't know how to change the width and height to 75px... I tried one code I found through Google, but I just got this error:

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Class 'Imagick' not found in C:\wamp\www\Legendary\new\usersettings.php on line 725
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0042  880616  {main}( )   ..\usersettings.php:0
```

Here's my current code (including the code which didn't work):

```
echo '
                    <table border="0" width="100%">
                    <tr><td style="font-size: 16px;">Change Image</td></tr>

                    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <tr><td>Upload Image:</td><td style="text-align: right;"><input type="file" name="upimage" id="upimage" /></td></tr>
                        <tr><td></td><td style="text-align: right; font-size: 10px;"></td></tr>
                        <tr><td></td><td style="text-align: right;"><input type="submit" name="submitnewimage" value="Upload" class="button" /></td></tr>
                    </form>
                    ';

                    echo '
                    </table>
                    ';

                    if(isset($_POST['submitnewimage'])){
                        $name = $_FILES['upimage']['name'];
                        $temp = $_FILES['upimage']['tmp_name'];
                        $type = $_FILES['upimage']['type'];
                        $size = $_FILES['upimage']['size'];
                        if($name!=""){
                            include 'config.php';
                            $sql5 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
                            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql5)) {
                                if(!isset($show2)){
                                    $id = $row['id'];
                                    $id = $id + 1;

                                    $show2 = "YES";
                                }
                            }

                            if(($type=="image/jpeg") || ($type=="image/jpg") || ($type=="image/gif") || ($type=="image/pjpeg") || ($type=="image/png")){
                                if($size<=100000){
                                    $pos = strrpos($name, '.');
                                    if($pos === false)
                                        $ext = "";
                                    $ext = substr($name, $pos);
                                    $newFilename = $id.$ext;

                                    move_uploaded_file($temp, "images/teamicons/".$newFilename);
                                    $im = new Imagick('images/teamicons/'.$newFilename); 
                                    $im->thumbnailImage(75,75); 
                                    $im->writeImage('images/teamicons/'.$newFilename);

                                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `images`(`id`, `name`, `size`, `type`) VALUES (NULL,'$newFilename',$size,'$type')");
                                    $myusername = $_SESSION['myusername'];
                                    mysql_query("UPDATE `members` SET `img`= '$newFilename' WHERE `username`='$myusername'");

                                    header("Location:" . $_SESSION['prev_page']);
                                }else{echo "<tr><td colspan='2'><span style='color:#F00;'>The file, &quot;".$name."&quot;, is too large! Maximum allowed file size is 100kB.</span></td></tr>";}
                            }else{echo "<tr><td colspan='2'><span style='color:#F00;'>&quot;".$type."&quot; is not a valid file type!</span></td></tr>";}
                        }else{echo "<tr><td colspan='2'><span style='color:#F00;'>No file has been specified!</span></td></tr>";}
                    }
```

Is there any way of changing the width and height of the images?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've successfully used [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) to do this recently, specifically using the `imagecopyresampled` function.

---

To expand a little on that... Once I had the image uploaded (which I wont go into, because that is a whole other issue), I did something fairly simple like this:

```
$original_info = getimagesize($filename);
$original_w = $original_info[0];
$original_h = $original_info[1];
$original_img = imagecreatefromjpg($filename);
$thumb_w = 100;
$thumb_h = 100;
$thumb_img = imagecreatetruecolor($thumb_w, $thumb_h);
imagecopyresampled($thumb_img, $original_img,
                   0, 0,
                   0, 0,
                   $thumb_w, $thumb_h,
                   $original_w, $original_h);
imagejpeg($thumb_img, $thumb_filename);
imagedestroy($thumb_img);
imagedestroy($original_img);
```

Please note that I have not tested this code. It's just here to give you a basic idea of my method.

Comment: in imagecopyresampled don't dst_w and dst_h come before src_w and src_h? you have them after.

Comment: line #4: imagecreatefromjpg should be imagecreatefromjpeg
shouldn't it? for those who will try to use the script

Answer (score 1):

The Imagick Class is not found, because it is a PHP extension you need to install on your server.

Read the following documentation to find instructions on how to use/install the extension.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

Comment: It seems like the download link is gone... Do you know any other way of doing this?

Comment: @Zytex, or you can do it client side, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8978748/684229)

Answer (score 1):

Simple solutions some times changed alfa (transparent png).
For me forks only this (it's real, just copy-pasted code)

```
public static function resize($filename, $maxW, $maxH, $ext = null)
{
    if ($ext === null)
        $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    else
        $ext = strtolower($ext);

    list($origW, $origH) = getimagesize($filename);

    $w = $origW;
    $h = $origH;

    # taller
    if ($h > $maxH) {
        $w = ($maxH / $h) * $w;
        $h = $maxH;
    }

    # wider
    if ($w > $maxW) {
        $h = ($maxW / $w) * $h;
        $w = $maxW;
    }


    $resource = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
    # MUST IMPORTANT TWO ROWS
    imagesavealpha($resource, true);
    imagefill($resource, 0, 0, 0x7fffffff);

    if ($ext == 'jpeg' || $ext == 'jpg') {
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
    } else if ($ext == 'png') {
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
    } else {
        throw new Exception('Unsupported extension');
    }

    imagecopyresampled(
        $resource,
        $image, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        $w, $h, $origW, $origH
    );
    imagedestroy($image);

    return $resource;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use code like this:

```
$t = imagecreatefromjpeg($old_path);
$x = imagesx($t);
$y = imagesy($t);

$s = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);

imagecopyresampled($s, $t, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height,
        $x, $y);

imagejpeg($s, $new_path);
chmod($new_path, 0644);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also scale the image client-side, e.g. using [plupload library](http://plupload.com/) (can resize JPEG and PNG).